# How to select next workflow activity using Core Service?

Tags: workflow

I have a decision activity and using the core service I want to finish the current activity, assign the next person and the next activity.  This is working fine for a manual activity where I only need to assign the person.

However, the decision activity also requires the next activity to perform and I don't know how to set it.  Here is my error:
"The next Workflow Activity has not been selected."  Any ideas?

Here is my code so far:

```
using (SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(binding))
{
    // Get Component
    var wfItem = client.Read(componentUri, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
    if (wfItem == null)
        return;

    // Get Workflow info for Component
    var activityUri = wfItem.WorkflowInfo.ActivityInstance.IdRef;
    var activityTitle = wfItem.WorkflowInfo.ActivityInstance.Title;

    // Set Finish Message
    ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData();
    finishData.Message = finishMessage;

    // Set Previous performer
    LinkToTrusteeData guiltyPerson = new LinkToTrusteeData();
    TridionHelper tridionHelper = new TridionHelper();
    guiltyPerson.IdRef = tridionHelper.GetPreviousAssigneeUri(componentUri, activityUri, activityTitle);
    finishData.NextAssignee = guiltyPerson;

    // Finish
    client.FinishActivity(activityUri, finishData, new ReadOptions());
}
```

Comment: You need to use the `DecisionActivityFinishData`. Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11537828/1269175

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion - exactly what I was hoping for.  Maybe you should put this as an answer, even if it is answered elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting answer from Frank here for community users convenience.

You need to use `DecisionActivityFinishData` instead of of `ActivityFinishData`.

```
var decisionActivityFinishData = new DecisionActivityFinishData
{
  NextActivity = new LinkToActivityDefinitionData{IdRef = "next activity ID"}
};
csClient.FinishActivity(currentactivity.Id, decisionActivityFinishData, 
                        readoption);
```